# Efficient way to update SQL 'relationship' table

Tags: sql, mysql, web-applications, normalization

Say I have three properly normalised tables. One of people, one of qualifications and one mapping people to qualifications:

People:

```
id | Name
----------
1  | Alice
2  | Bob
```

Degrees:

```
id | Name
---------
1  | PhD
2  | MA
```

People-to-degrees:

```
person_id | degree_id
---------------------
1         | 2         # Alice has an MA
2         | 1         # Bob has a PhD
```

So then I have to update this mapping via my web interface. (I made a mistake. Bob has a BA, not a PhD, and Alice just got her B Eng.)

There are four possible states of these one-to-many relationship mappings:

- was true before, should now be false
- was false before, should now be true
- was true before, should remain true
- was false before, should remain false

what I don't want to do is read the values from four checkboxes, then hit the database four times to say "Did Bob have a BA before? Well he does now." "Did Bob have PhD before? Because he doesn't any more" and so on.

How do other people address this issue?

I'm curious to see if someone else arrives at the same solution I did.

**UPDATE 1**: onedaywhen suggests the same thing which occurred to me -- simply delete all the old entries, correct or not, and INSERT new ones.

**UPDATE 2**: potatopeelings suggests adding some code to the form which stores the original value of the field which can be compared with the new value on submit.

Comment: what are the controls on your web interface? All check boxes for values in People and Degrees table?
Is one update for one People?

Comment: I hope this answer will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273815/if-exists-before-insert-update-delete-for-optimization/2275340#2275340

Comment: You can adopt different strategies depending on your particular database and version

Comment: That answer does address the issue, but only for a particular type of SQL server, unless I'm confused.

Comment: The MERGE is for SQL Server 2008. But the BEGIN TRAN - COMMIT sample would work for prior versions.

Comment: Yes, Ismail, they're check boxes. And josephj, I'm hoping for general comment on the issue rather than something implementation-specific. I normally use MySQL.

Comment: I see that now. But I can't use MERGE in MySQL so I'm still searching for a generalised answer, thank you.

Comment: In that case you could have tagged your question with MySQL. I will do it.

Answer (score 2):

Logically, an `UPDATE` is a `DELETE` followed by an `INSERT` (consider that SQL Server triggers can access logical tables named `inserted` and `deleted` but there is no `updated` table). So you should be able to hit the database only twice i.e. first `DELETE` all rows (correct or otherwise) for Bob, second `INSERT` all correct rows for Bob.

If you want to hit the database only once, consider using Standard SQL's `MERGE`, assuming your DBMS supports it (SQL Server introduced it in 2008).

Comment: Aha! That "first DELETE, then INSERT" seemed to me like the most elegant way around the complexity. Anyone care to comment? onedaywhen's answer doesn't have either up- or down-votes...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the UI is a checkbox grid (1. in Ismail comment in the question)

```
           MA      PhD    
Alice      x 
Bob                 x
```

where the x represents checked boxes. I'd go with using the front-end script to send only the **changes** back to the server. Then doing the INSERTs and DELETEs in the People-to-degrees under a single transaction, or a MERGE (as pointed out in Ismail's link)

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT query
DELETE query
COMMIT
```

You would pass the INSERT (and DELETE) query a list of people ID, degree ID pairs like. For your example, the INSERT query would be the single pair (2,2) and for the DELETE query the single pair (2,1).

Comment: How would the front-end script send only the changes? Are you saying that for every checkbox, there would be a corresponding <input type="hidden"> with the original value?

Comment: That is one way of doing it. Other ways are
1. Add an extra attribute to the checkbox with the old value, which you can later access with a .getAttribute
2. Add an onclick event to each checkbox that keeps track of changes
3. Build a string / array of the grid values onload of the page, and onsubmit compare the submitted values with that (string built on onload).

Comment: I'm old school. I wasn't thinking of relying on a client side scripting language!