# Update one to many relationship data in database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I want to update a list in the database which has one to many relationship.

For example, There are over 100 subjects and a student can select whatever he wants. Let's say next time that student edit his selection.

What is the way you would update the database for this case? What I am used to doing is delete all the past selections and add all the newly selected subjects. This is pretty easy logic but I am just wondering whether there is a better way to do this in terms of performance. In my case 'delete' is a single database call and inserting all is a loop in a single database connection.

I understand we can add a logic to identify the deleted records and newly added records. Is it realy worth to do that? What you would do for similar cases?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient way to update SQL 'relationship' table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042644/efficient-way-to-update-sql-relationship-table)

Comment: @one There may be a real duplicate, but your linked question is sufficiently different. You say there to delete-insert (as answer). Here the question itself is, is there any better than delete-insert? The other question deals with 2 relationships. This question deals with a multi-attribute relationship expressed as 1:N against a single parent.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: have you read "The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions" ? (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) I don't think posting duplicate answers is in the spirit of SO.

Comment: @one In your link, have you seen **If you’re going to close a user’s question as a duplicate, it has to be a real duplicate.**? Find me an exact duplicate first

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: "Find me an exact duplicate first" -- I suspect I can't do that, it's subjective. That's why we have upvotes and downvotes, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For brevity and simplicity, there is nothing really wrong with a delete-reinsert approach, barring foreign key hooks from child tables or triggers firing for each (re)insert.

Another way to do it could be to pass the new set as a table-valued parameter to a SP to Sql Server, which would then use a duo of queries to make the change

```
delete many_table
where studentid=@studentid and someid not in (select someid from @tableparam p)

insert many_table(studentid, someid)
select @studentid, p.someid
from @tableparam p left join many_table t on p.someid=t.someid and t.studentid=@studentid
where t.someid is null
```

(there is a more elegant MERGE syntax for SQL Server 2008, which is yet another option, further testing your TSQL skills)

Comment: Six and one half dozen of the other... your choice

Comment: It's ok as long as your delete/insert is atomic.  If you're not doing it under commitment control and someone reads the table in the middle of your update you could get into trouble.

Comment: @one The fact that you cannot find the exact duplicate speaks for itself

Comment: @one It's not nice to down-vote just because you disagree with the person/meta-approach (not answer related), rather than the answer

Comment: Upvoted to neutralize downvote. This is a useful answer regardless of whether it was asked before.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: it's not nice IMO to clog SO up with duplicate answers. Down voting is the community way of expressing such opinions, no?